# Unable to build Flink from sources due to MapR artifacts problems

Tags: apache-flink, mapr

Summary: `mapr` dependency could not be found and thus the `Flink` build on master branch fails.

```
Failed to execute goal on project flink-mapr-fs: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-mapr-fs:jar:1.10-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr
```

`MapR` has been in shutdown talks as a company - i'm unclear as to whether they're even open. What is the answer/ what to do here?  I'd like to simply "skip"/ignore the mapr connector but not sure how to do so..

Details:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project flink-mapr-fs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-mapr-fs:jar:1.10-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-mapr-fs:jar:1.10-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:pom:5.2.1-mapr from/to mapr-releases (https://repository.mapr.com/maven/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:pom:5.2.1-mapr from/to mapr-releases (https://repository.mapr.com/maven/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just verify you have the below entry in "flink/flink-filesystems/flink-mapr-fs/pom.xml"

```
<profile>
    <id>unsafe-mapr-repo</id>
    <activation>
            <property>
                    <name>unsafe-mapr-repo</name>
            </property>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <!-- MapR -->
        <repository>
                <id>mapr-releases</id>              
                <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>                                
                <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>                             
                <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

Once it is verified, run the below command from "flink/flink-filesystems/flink-mapr-fs", to ensure the build was successful for the below project.
`mvn clean package -DskipTests -Punsafe-mapr-repo`.
Once this is successful, run the same maven package command from "flink/flink-filesystems", to ensure the build was successful and after that you should be good to run from flink project.
This will ensure that you have a successful target-build for the flink project.

Comment: This looks promising: i am trying it out. Note the `mapr-fs/pom.xml` is already as you showed. So I added the command line switch `-Punsafe-mapr-repo` to `mvn` command as you showed. Let's see.

Comment: it's downloading from the 'unsafe' `mapr` repo now. V nice.  btw I work < 1 mile from mapr office  maybe I'll swing by and see if they're actually still "alive" over there ;)